# Gorm Find() query not populating all fields defined in the defined struct holding the result set

Tags: go, grails-orm

The problem that I've is **tx** returned in result set doesn't have all fields set. Not able to figure out why? It has value in the actual database table.

```
// request object supplied in FetchTransactionWithHighestExpiry:
type ProvisionRequest struct {
        Identity string     `json:"identity"`
        IdentityType string `json:"identityType"`
}

// struct to model database table
type Transactions struct {
        Identity string `gorm:"index;not null"`
        IdentityType string 
}

// method where there is problem
func (c *DBClient) FetchTransactionWithHighestExpiry(req *model.ProvisionRequest) (model.Transactions, error)  {
    var tx model.Transactions
    res := c.client.Model(&model.Transactions{}).Where("identity = ? AND endDate  > ?", req.Identity, time.Now().Unix()).Order("endDate desc").First(&tx)
    return tx, res.Error
}
```

My tx has only value of identity set whereas identityType is an empty string. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

Edit 1: transactions table schema

```
-- rp.transactions definition

CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `transaction_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `identity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `identityType` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serviceId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `partnerId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `startDate` int NOT NULL,
  `endDate` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `identity_idx` (`identity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: how are `Identity` and `IdentityType` columns named in your `transactions` table?

Comment: identity and identityType. Note, Identity gets populated correctly. Both are varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [default](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Column-Name), when constructing a query, gorm will use snake_case convention to convert `Identity` and `IdentityType` fields to `identity` and `identity_type` columns.

If your table columns are named differently, you need to specify this.

```
// struct to model database table
type Transactions struct {
        Identity string `gorm:"index;not null"`
        IdentityType string `gorm:"column:identityType"`
}
```

Comment: Accepted. This key thing isn't highlighted enough in their documentation or is simply not there.